# Ajax scraping: getElementByTagName as plaintext

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a URL that I'd like to scrape a certain bit of information from and I'd preferably do that by obtaining the element. I'd also need to get it as plaintext, but I'm still pretty new to Ajax/jQuery and don't quite know what the correct syntax is..

My ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
     url: URL,
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(data) {
          var info = data; //How can I get a table from the data without loading the whole site extracting a small portion? 
          if(info != undefined) {
            console.log(info); //Needs to be plaintext.
          }

      }
  });
```

I hope my question is clear... I'm essentially loading a website and retrieving a table or class name as plaintext... How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Is this part of a browser extension? Otherwise it looks like you'll get in trouble with cross site scripting. Have you been able to make the request and get the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options on the client-side are:

1.) First, optionally use a regular expression to isolate that tag contents, but this is usually considered rather costly.

2.) Create a node, then drop the text into it's innerHTML.

That's usually the standard way of rendering text responses to the DOM.

Neither one are all that lightweight.

If you just need to pick something out of the text, use Regular Expression. Also, as mentioned, be aware of XSS and cross-origin policy.

Additionally, you may want to handle this on the server-side.